# How to push a file to GitHub using an Android app (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, github

So i have a excel file on my GitHub that needs to be updated so i plan to update it using a application

How do I push the updated excel file to GitHub directly from the app using a button
(Java language)

Could someone point me in the right direction

Mostly when i search this question the results are about how to push the code to GitHub

Comment: "How do I push the updated excel file to GitHub" -- you might want to edit your question and explain in greater detail what you mean. For example, you might explain how you would accomplish this outside of your app, using the GitHub Web UI or Git clients. My guess is that "push the updated excel file" means that you want to have a cloned Git repo on the phone, and you want to commit and push changes to the upstream repo from your app. If so, you would need to look at Java/Kotlin Git libraries.

Comment: Git libraries for java got it

Comment: I am not sure how i could explain it more i am new to coding and this is just an idea i haven't tried anything for now ....Rn if i have to add something to the excel file i make the changes and upload-push-commit it to GitHub so i was trying to make an app which has edit textviews where i can add the new values update the current excel file and then directly upload -push -commit it to GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java you maybe use Gradle(Usually used with android) or Maven as your project builder tool. I just googled quickly "Java git library" for you and JGit came up which seems to be a fairly simple library to use. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/jgit#:%7E:text=Introduction,used%20in%20the%20Java%20community.) is a tutorial on it.

You probably have to initialize the repo as usual from code or separately I suggest from code. And you need to implement file handling as well separately from this simple git client implementation. You might use this other [source](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-java) helpful for that.

But on native android there might be some different library for handling files as well as you should look into intents for passing different files or data between applications.

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: I am using Jxl for the excel editing part i just wanted to find out how to upload/push-commit that existing file to GitHub I'll look into the Jgit library thanks for the answer